# How do I get the title and complete class value?

Tags: php, preg-match, domdocument

I have two queries

1) `<div class="a b" title="my title">`
    How do I get the title and complete class value ? ('a' always be a fixed class but not 'b'. Second class can be anything and also possiblity to have more than two classes.)

2) `<h1><a link="dynamic_link" class="fix-class">my content< /a>< /h1>`
    Get all attributes(link,class..) of 'a href' tag which belongs to only 'h1' tag

Please help me out because I stuck on this point from last two days and not able to get any solution from google. This is my first quetion on stackoverflow. I hope I get many hands for help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have u tried codewise so far?

Comment: preg_match and domdocument

Comment: Have you tried [DOMElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php)? Because that sounds exactly like DOMElement.

Comment: Care to post a sample of the HTML?

Comment: U should post the relevant code that u have tried then more peeps are going to be willing to assist

Comment: Have you tried XPath queries (DOMXPath works fine)? If so, does that match your elements, or are you having trouble with it? What would be the XPath's you're using?

Comment: Hi I have re frame the question..Pls chk

Comment: @Wrikken..Hi..I haven't used xpath before.the thing is i checked many examples on net but they are not fit to my particular requirement.

Comment: @ An Phan Hi I have re frame the question. pls chk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should [use XPath to query HTML or XML](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php). To use XPath you have to [load you HTML into a DOMDocument object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

```
/* $doc is an instance of DOMDocument */

$xpath = new DOMXPath( $doc );

$myElemnts = $xpath->query( '//li[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " classA ")]' );
```

The XPath class matching example is from http://www.cowburn.info/2009/06/15/xpath-css-class/

Please refer to one of the many XPath manuals on the web, to find out how to get you queries written in XPath.

Comment: Thanks a lot feeela.. I got lead from your hint.